# Tensorflow - The kernel appears to have died. It will restart automatically

Tags: python, keras, jupyter-notebook, tensorflow2.0

I am reading `"Hands-On Machine Learning with Scikit-Learn, Keras and Tensorflow"` and installed `Tensorflow 2` as follows:

```
$ python3 -m pip install --upgrade tensorflow
```

In the `jupyter notebook` I tried to import `Tensorflow` as follows:

```
import tensorflow as tf
```

But then I get the following error message:

```
The kernel appears to have died. It will restart automatically
```

I know there is a bunch of StackOverflow threads about this topic. I have read them all. Some of them are old, some are new. Most of them suggest to downgrade the `Tensorflow` version to 1.5. But when I do that I can not use some of the methods of the `Keras API` (e.g. `load_data()` could not be found).

Is there anyone who have found a solution for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second version of the textbook is all about TensorFlow version 2 so you have to use TensorFlow version 2 to use code. if there is a problem get the first version of the textbook which uses TensorFlow 1.

But I suggest learning TensorFlow 2 as it is the latest version.
if you are using anaconda Try installing TensorFlow 2 in a new environment.
To create a new environment open anaconda prompt.

```
conda create -n envname python=3.6
```

and then activate the environment

```
activate envname
```

Now try installing TensorFlow 2 and other necessary modules
and check.

If it does not work the best solution is to use google colab(colab.research.google.com/).where you can do everything online, you can even have free GPU.

Comment: Thank you. This was exactly what I needed